# laravel 5.7 how to pass request of controller to model and save

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass `$request` from a function in controller to a function in model.

THis is my controller function:

PostController.php

```
public function store(Request $request, post $post)
{

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->description = $request->description;

    $post->save();

    return redirect(route('post.index'));

}
```

how save data in model Post.php?

I want the controller to only be in the role of sending information. Information is sent to the model. All calculations and storage are performed in the model

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean `how to save data in model?` the code you have is already saving the data

Comment: Thanks.I want the controller to only be in the role of sending information. Information is sent to the model. All calculations and storage are performed in the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find to answer my question :

pass `$request` to my_method in model Post.php :

PostController.php:

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post_model = new Post;
        $saved = $post_model->postStore($request);

        //$saved = response of my_method in model

        if($saved){
            return redirect(route('post.index'));
        }
    }
```

and save data in the model :

Post.php

we can return instance or boolean to the controller .

I returned bool (save method response) to controller :

```php
    public function postStore($request)
    {
        $this->title = $request->title;
        $this->description = $request->description;

        $saved = $this->save();

        //save method response bool

        return $saved;

    }
```

in this way, all calculations and storage are performed in the model (best way to save data in MVC)

Comment: I don't think you should return a response from your model. That's the responsibility of your controller.

Comment: This feels wrong. You're giving knowledge of a request to your model.

Comment: Model should not be responsible of returning the Response. that should remain the role of Controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it even easier. Laravel has it's own helper "request()", which can be called anywhere in your code.

So, generally, you can do this:

**PostController.php**

```php
    public function store()
    {
        $post_model = new Post;
        // for queries it's better to use transactions to handle errors
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
           $post_model->postStore();
           \DB::commit(); // if there was no errors, your query will be executed
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \DB::rollback(); // either it won't execute any statements and rollback your database to previous state
            abort(500);
        }
        // you don't need any if statements anymore. If you're here, it means all data has been saved successfully
        return redirect(route('post.index'));
    }
```

**Post.php**

```php
    public function postStore()
    {
        $request = request(); //save helper result to variable, so it can be reused
        $this->title = $request->title;
        $this->description = $request->description;
        $this->save();
    }
```

---

I'll show you full best practice example for update and create:

**web.php**

```php
    Route::post('store/post/{post?}', 'PostController@post')->name('post.store');
```

**yourform.blade.php** - can be used for update and create

```php
    <form action='{{ route('post.store', ['post' => $post->id ?? null]))'>
       <!-- some inputs here -->
       <!-- some inputs here -->

    </form>
```

**PostController.php**

```php
    public function update(Post $post) {
        // $post - if you sent null, in this variable will be 'new Post' result
        // either laravel will try to find id you provided in your view, like Post::findOrFail(1). Of course, if it can't, it'll abort(404)

        // then you can call your method postStore and it'll update or create for your new post.
        // anyway, I'd recommend you to do next

        \DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
          $post->fill(request()->all())->save();
          \DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
          \DB::rollback();
           abort(500);
        }
      return redirect(route('post.index'));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Well, probably you can make sth like this:


`public function store($id = null) {
     if ($id !== null) {
      $post_model = Post::findOrFail($id); // if it won't be available to find your post, it'll throw abort(404)
     } else {
       $post_model = new Post();
     }
}`
That's it. The rest code will work for both - update and create

Answer (score 2):

Based on description, not sure what you want exactly but assuming you want a clean controller and model . Here is one way

#### Model - Post

```
class Post {
    $fillable = array(
        'title', 'description'
    );
}
```

#### PostController

```
class PostController extend Controller {

    // store function normally don't get Casted Objects as `Post`
    function store(\Request $request) {

        $parameters = $request->all(); // get all your request data as an array

        $post = \Post::create($parameters); // create method expect an array of fields mentioned in $fillable and returns a save dinstance
        // OR
        $post = new \Post();
        $post->fill($parameters);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new model simply by instantiating it:

```
$post = new Post;  //Post is your model
```

then put content in record

```
$post->title = $request->title;
$post->description = $request->description;
```

and finally save it to db later:

```
$post->save();
```

To save all data in model using create method.You need to setup Mass Assignments when using create and set columns in fillable property in model.

```
  protected $fillable = [ 'title', 'description' ];
```

and then call this with input

```
    $post = Post::create([ 'parametername'  => 'parametervalue' ]);

and if request has unwanted entries like token then us except on request before passing.

    $post = Post::create([ $request->except(['_token']) ]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did the same. But I want to do all these steps in the model

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $book = new Song();
    
    $book->title = $request['title'];
    $book->artist = $request['artist'];
    $book->rating = $request['rating'];
    $book->album_id = $request['album_id'];
    
    $result=  $book->save();
 }
```